# Knockout if statement ignored when adding new content to viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

This is my last knockout question :)

I have an if statement setup and is working when the page is loaded for the first time however whenever I try adding any new items to my view model the if statement is not fired.

My [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/wR6mb/1/)

Why does it work when I initialize the viewmodel the first time however not when adding other items. I dont get any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use brackets on qtype as part of the if expression, i.e.:

```
<!-- ko if: qtype() === 'Rating' -->
```

Also, don't you want to have your arrayMap iterator return an instance of your Question view model? I.e.:

```
self.questions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(questions, function(question) {
    return new Question(question.question, question.qtype);
}));
```

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wR6mb/15/